# Mocha ending test run before completing all tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, jenkins, mocha.js, xunit

I'm currently working in a CI flow using Jenkins that triggers mocha tests against a nodejs server backend.

For some reasong xunit test reporter was not working with jenkins. The test-resul.xml was coming out empty and the job kept failing. We were able to get it working by running:

```
npm install mocha-jenkins-reporter
```

Right before the test's trigger shown below:

```
JUNIT_REPORT_PATH=test_report.xml JUNIT_REPORT_STACK=1 NODE_ENV=test node ./node_modules/.bin/mocha --globals * --reporter mocha-jenkins-reporter --no-colors
```

Now I'm getting a partial result, as for some reason not all tests are running. They are stopping in the middle of the test suite without any notice or error message. I've also noticed that the xml generated is missing the root element closing **tag** . I worked around that by running:

```
echo '</testsuites>' >> test-result.xml
```

In addition to that, I've noticed memory consumption spikes during test's execution.
This is the npm install output, this step is the first step of this job:

```
+ npm -v
3.8.6
+ npm install
npm WARN deprecated sequelize@3.14.2: security/injection issue with limit/offset fixed in 3.17.0
npm WARN deprecated lodash@0.9.2: Grunt needs your help! See https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/1403.
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs version 3 and before will fail on newer node releases. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible.
npm WARN deprecated jade@0.26.3: Jade has been renamed to pug, please install the latest version of pug instead of jade
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@2.0.3: graceful-fs version 3 and before will fail on newer node releases. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible.

> ws@0.6.5 install /home/jenkins/workspace/Rufus_Test_DEV/node_modules/ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


> actionhero@10.0.3 postinstall /home/jenkins/workspace/Rufus_Test_DEV
> echo 'To generate a new actionhero project, run "node ./node_modules/.bin/actionhero generate"'

To generate a new actionhero project, run "node ./node_modules/.bin/actionhero generate"
actionhero@10.0.3 /home/jenkins/workspace/Rufus_Test_DEV
+-- async@0.9.2 
+-- aws-sdk@2.3.3 
| +-- jmespath@0.15.0 
| +-- sax@1.1.5 
| +-- xml2js@0.4.15 
| `-- xmlbuilder@2.6.2 
|   `-- lodash@3.5.0 
+-- bcrypt-nodejs@0.0.3 
+-- blanket@1.2.3 
| +-- acorn@1.2.2 
| +-- falafel@1.2.0 
| +-- foreach@2.0.5 
| +-- isarray@0.0.1 
| +-- object-keys@1.0.9 
| `-- xtend@4.0.1 
+-- braintree@1.37.1 
| +-- dateformat@1.0.1-1.2.3 
| +-- depd@1.1.0 
| +-- readable-stream@1.1.10 
| | +-- core-util-is@1.0.2 
| | +-- debuglog@0.0.2 
| | `-- string_decoder@0.10.31 
| +-- semver@5.1.0 
| +-- source-map-support@0.2.9 
| | `-- source-map@0.1.32 
| +-- underscore@1.3.1 
| `-- xml2js@0.1.13 
+-- browser_fingerprint@0.0.6 
+-- circular-json@0.1.6 
| `-- wru@0.2.7 
+-- coveralls@2.11.9 
| +-- js-yaml@3.0.1 
| | +-- argparse@0.1.16 
| | | +-- underscore@1.7.0 
| | | `-- underscore.string@2.4.0 
| | `-- esprima@1.0.4 
| +-- lcov-parse@0.0.6 
| +-- log-driver@1.2.4 
| +-- minimist@1.2.0 
| `-- request@2.67.0 
|   +-- bl@1.0.3 
|   | `-- readable-stream@2.0.6 
|   |   `-- isarray@1.0.0 
|   `-- qs@5.2.0 
+-- easy-table@0.3.0 
+-- emailjs@1.0.4 
| +-- addressparser@0.3.2 
| +-- bufferjs@1.1.0 
| +-- mimelib@0.2.14 
| | +-- addressparser@0.2.1 
| | `-- encoding@0.1.12 
| |   `-- iconv-lite@0.4.13 
| +-- moment@2.11.2 
| `-- starttls@1.0.1 
+-- fakeredis@0.3.4 
| `-- redis@2.1.0 
+-- formidable@1.0.17 
+-- geolib@2.0.20 
+-- grunt@0.4.5 
| +-- async@0.1.22 
| +-- coffee-script@1.3.3 
| +-- colors@0.6.2 
| +-- dateformat@1.0.2-1.2.3 
| +-- eventemitter2@0.4.14 
| +-- exit@0.1.2 
| +-- findup-sync@0.1.3 
| | +-- glob@3.2.11 
| | | `-- minimatch@0.3.0 
| | `-- lodash@2.4.2 
| +-- getobject@0.1.0 
| +-- glob@3.1.21 
| | +-- graceful-fs@1.2.3 
| | `-- inherits@1.0.2 
| +-- grunt-legacy-log@0.1.3 
| | +-- grunt-legacy-log-utils@0.1.1 
| | | +-- lodash@2.4.2 
| | | `-- underscore.string@2.3.3 
| | +-- lodash@2.4.2 
| | `-- underscore.string@2.3.3 
| +-- grunt-legacy-util@0.2.0 
| | +-- async@0.1.22 
| | `-- lodash@0.9.2 
| +-- hooker@0.2.3 
| +-- iconv-lite@0.2.11 
| +-- js-yaml@2.0.5 
| +-- lodash@0.9.2 
| +-- minimatch@0.2.14 
| | +-- lru-cache@2.7.3 
| | `-- sigmund@1.0.1 
| +-- nopt@1.0.10 
| | `-- abbrev@1.0.7 
| +-- rimraf@2.2.8 
| +-- underscore.string@2.2.1 
| `-- which@1.0.9 
+-- jsonwebtoken@5.4.1 
| +-- jws@3.1.3 
| | +-- base64url@1.0.6 
| | | +-- concat-stream@1.4.10 
| | | `-- meow@2.0.0 
| | |   +-- camelcase-keys@1.0.0 
| | |   | `-- map-obj@1.0.1 
| | |   +-- indent-string@1.2.2 
| | |   | +-- get-stdin@4.0.1 
| | |   | `-- repeating@1.1.3 
| | |   |   `-- is-finite@1.0.1 
| | |   |     `-- number-is-nan@1.0.0 
| | |   `-- object-assign@1.0.0 
| | `-- jwa@1.1.3 
| |   +-- buffer-equal-constant-time@1.0.1 
| |   `-- ecdsa-sig-formatter@1.0.5 
| |     `-- base64-url@1.2.2 
| `-- ms@0.7.1 
+-- le_node@1.2.0 
| +-- babel-runtime@5.4.7 
| | `-- core-js@0.9.16 
| +-- codependency@0.1.3 
| | `-- semver@2.2.1 
| +-- json-stringify-safe@5.0.1 
| +-- lodash@3.9.3 
| `-- semver@5.1.0 
+-- lodash@4.11.1 
+-- machina@1.1.2 
| `-- lodash@3.10.1 
+-- mime@1.2.11 
+-- mocha@2.4.5 
| +-- commander@2.3.0 
| +-- debug@2.2.0 
| +-- diff@1.4.0 
| +-- escape-string-regexp@1.0.2 
| +-- glob@3.2.3 
| | +-- graceful-fs@2.0.3 
| | `-- inherits@2.0.1 
| +-- growl@1.8.1 
| +-- jade@0.26.3 
| | +-- commander@0.6.1 
| | `-- mkdirp@0.3.0 
| +-- mkdirp@0.5.1 
| | `-- minimist@0.0.8 
| `-- supports-color@1.2.0 
+-- mocha-lcov-reporter@0.0.1 
+-- moment@2.10.6 
+-- moment-timezone@0.4.1 
+-- mysql@2.10.2 
| +-- bignumber.js@2.1.4 
| `-- readable-stream@1.1.14 
+-- node-gcm@0.12.1 
| `-- debug@0.8.1 
+-- node-resque@0.11.6 
+-- node-schedule@0.2.9 
| +-- cron-parser@0.6.2 
| `-- long-timeout@0.0.2 
+-- node-uuid@1.4.7 
+-- optimist@0.6.1 
| +-- minimist@0.0.10 
| `-- wordwrap@0.0.3 
+-- paypal-ipn@3.0.0 
+-- primus@2.4.12 
| +-- access-control@0.0.8 
| | +-- millisecond@0.1.2 
| | `-- vary@1.0.1 
| +-- create-server@0.0.7 
| | `-- connected@0.0.2 
| +-- diagnostics@0.0.4 
| | +-- color@0.7.3 
| | | +-- color-convert@0.5.3 
| | | `-- color-string@0.2.4 
| | |   `-- color-name@1.0.1 
| | +-- colornames@0.0.2 
| | +-- env-variable@0.0.3 
| | +-- kuler@0.0.0 
| | `-- text-hex@0.0.0 
| +-- eventemitter3@0.1.6 
| +-- forwarded-for@0.1.1 
| +-- fusing@0.4.0 
| | +-- emits@1.0.2 
| | `-- predefine@0.1.2 
| |   `-- extendible@0.1.1 
| +-- load@1.0.2 
| +-- setheader@0.0.4 
| | `-- debug@0.7.4 
| `-- ultron@1.0.2 
+-- qrcode-js@0.0.2 
+-- querystring@0.2.0 
+-- redis@0.12.1 
+-- redis-sentinel-client@0.2.5 
| `-- redis@0.10.3 
+-- request@2.71.0  invalid
| +-- aws-sign2@0.6.0 
| +-- aws4@1.3.2 
| | `-- lru-cache@4.0.1 
| |   +-- pseudomap@1.0.2 
| |   `-- yallist@2.0.0 
| +-- bl@1.1.2 
| | `-- readable-stream@2.0.6 
| |   +-- isarray@1.0.0 
| |   +-- process-nextick-args@1.0.6 
| |   `-- util-deprecate@1.0.2 
| +-- caseless@0.11.0 
| +-- combined-stream@1.0.5 
| | `-- delayed-stream@1.0.0 
| +-- extend@3.0.0 
| +-- forever-agent@0.6.1 
| +-- form-data@1.0.0-rc4 
| | `-- async@1.5.2 
| +-- har-validator@2.0.6 
| | +-- chalk@1.1.3 
| | | +-- ansi-styles@2.2.1 
| | | +-- escape-string-regexp@1.0.5 
| | | +-- has-ansi@2.0.0 
| | | | `-- ansi-regex@2.0.0 
| | | +-- strip-ansi@3.0.1 
| | | `-- supports-color@2.0.0 
| | +-- commander@2.9.0 
| | | `-- graceful-readlink@1.0.1 
| | +-- is-my-json-valid@2.13.1 
| | | +-- generate-function@2.0.0 
| | | +-- generate-object-property@1.2.0 
| | | | `-- is-property@1.0.2 
| | | `-- jsonpointer@2.0.0 
| | `-- pinkie-promise@2.0.1 
| |   `-- pinkie@2.0.4 
| +-- hawk@3.1.3 
| | +-- boom@2.10.1 
| | +-- cryptiles@2.0.5 
| | +-- hoek@2.16.3 
| | `-- sntp@1.0.9 
| +-- http-signature@1.1.1 
| | +-- assert-plus@0.2.0 
| | +-- jsprim@1.2.2 
| | | +-- extsprintf@1.0.2 
| | | +-- json-schema@0.2.2 
| | | `-- verror@1.3.6 
| | `-- sshpk@1.7.4 
| |   +-- asn1@0.2.3 
| |   +-- dashdash@1.13.0 
| |   | `-- assert-plus@1.0.0 
| |   +-- ecc-jsbn@0.1.1 
| |   +-- jodid25519@1.0.2 
| |   +-- jsbn@0.1.0 
| |   `-- tweetnacl@0.14.3 
| +-- is-typedarray@1.0.0 
| +-- isstream@0.1.2 
| +-- json-stringify-safe@5.0.1 
| +-- mime-types@2.1.10 
| | `-- mime-db@1.22.0 
| +-- oauth-sign@0.8.1 
| +-- qs@6.1.0 
| +-- stringstream@0.0.5 
| +-- tough-cookie@2.2.2 
| `-- tunnel-agent@0.4.2 
+-- sequelize@3.14.2 
| +-- bluebird@3.3.5 
| +-- dottie@1.1.1 
| +-- generic-pool@2.2.1 
| +-- inflection@1.9.0 
| +-- lodash@3.10.1 
| +-- shimmer@1.1.0 
| +-- toposort-class@1.0.1 
| +-- validator@4.9.0 
| +-- wellknown@0.4.1 
| | +-- concat-stream@1.5.1 
| | | +-- readable-stream@2.0.6 
| | | | `-- isarray@1.0.0 
| | | `-- typedarray@0.0.6 
| | `-- minimist@1.1.3 
| `-- wkx@0.1.0 
+-- should@4.6.5 
| +-- should-equal@0.3.1 
| +-- should-format@0.0.7 
| `-- should-type@0.0.4 
+-- uglify-js@2.4.24 
| +-- async@0.2.10 
| +-- source-map@0.1.34 
| | `-- amdefine@1.0.0 
| +-- uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2 
| `-- yargs@3.5.4 
|   +-- camelcase@1.2.1 
|   +-- decamelize@1.2.0 
|   +-- window-size@0.1.0 
|   `-- wordwrap@0.0.2 
+-- winston@0.8.3 
| +-- async@0.2.10 
| +-- cycle@1.0.3 
| +-- eyes@0.1.8 
| +-- pkginfo@0.3.1 
| `-- stack-trace@0.0.9 
+-- winston-loggly@1.3.1 
| `-- loggly@1.1.0 
|   +-- request@2.67.0 
|   | +-- bl@1.0.3 
|   | | `-- readable-stream@2.0.6 
|   | |   `-- isarray@1.0.0 
|   | `-- qs@5.2.0 
|   `-- timespan@2.3.0 
`-- ws@0.6.5 
  +-- nan@1.4.3 
  `-- options@0.0.6 

npm WARN actionhero@10.0.3 No license field.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems likely that the memory spikes are a smoking gun - you're exceeding either a resource quota and getting killed, or simply crashing. This seems to be confirmed by the partial file created - files that end literally in the middle of a piece like that are a strong indicator of a crash or force-kill.

I use ActionHero myself, and it uses very little memory. Sequelize is the bulk of its usage and even then it's rare that I use more than 180MB of RAM on a production API node. You weren't specific about how big your "memory spike" is, but I would start with some investigation into exactly how much your process is using and how it's allocated. There are LOTS of tools available for this, but I would suggest using something like StrongLoop, PM2, NewRelic, or Ruxit if just because it's going to help you find it quickly. There are free or trial options available for all those tools.

Beyond that, you can also do some investigation by running the tests individually. When you call `mocha` you can pass in one test suite to execute

Finally, if you're using Bash as your shell, try removing the `--globals *` as a test. Bash may be expanding that before executing Mocha, replacing it with a list of files in the current working directory. If that turns out to be throwing anything off, you can put it in quotes or create a `mocha.opts` file. Here's mine, just as an example:

```
--recursive
--reporter spec
--timeout 15000
--ignore-leaks
--slow 3000
--globals api,assert
--require test/bootstrap
test
```

Note that command-line args can override opts-file settings. That's why I have `--reporter spec` here - this reduces my typing to run `mocha` manually in my local dev environment (I can just run `mocha` with no params at all). You can still set the reporter to the one you want in your CI stack.

Comment: Indeed, it definitely looks like a resource allocation problem. Thanks for the tips on the profiling tools, I'm off to test them now and I return with what I found, and if this is the root cause accept your answer. Thanks for the awesome and quick answer.

Comment: Hey Chad, another thing, I'm running this on a Docker container, do you know if it is ok to run npm install every build? Is this the recommended setting or should I commit those dependencies to the initial docker image.

Comment: If you're in a Docker container perhaps you're hitting a hard memory limit in your management layer. Most Docker managers like Kube, Mesos, ECS, Rancher, etc. have these. Try increasing it. And yes, it's OK to run that every build, but typically you want to run `npm update` instead. That installs any missing packages AND processes any required updates. `npm install` only does the install.